# using a while loop and defined function to play bunco

Tags: python, function

I am currently writing a code for bunco at the moment and defining and calling a function take_turn(playernum). What this is supposed to do is check the current player's score rolls the dice and returns the new value to the player. I am also using this in a while loop. Problem is that there is an infinite loop displayed on the shell whenever I execute the program, how would I fix this? Here is the current progress I have at the moment.

```
from random import randint

roundnum=1
player1=0
player2=0
dice1=randint(1,6)
dice2=randint(1,6)
dice3=randint(1,6)
def take_turn(playernumber):
    print (dice1,dice2,dice3)
    while dice1!=6 or dice2!=6 or dice3!=6:
        if dice1==6 or dice2==6 or dice3==6:
            playernumber+=1
        elif dice1==6 and dice2==6:
            playernumber+=5
        elif dice1==6 and dice3==6:
            playernumber+=5
        elif dice2==6 and dice3==6:
            playernumber+=5
        elif dice1==6 and dice2==6 and dice3==6:
            playernumber+=21
        if roundnum==dice1 or roundnum==dice2 or roundnum==dice3:
            playernumber+= roundnum
        if dice1==dice2==dice3:
            continue
        else:
            print (playernumber)
            return 
while player1<=20 and player2<=20:
    take_turn(player1)
    take_turn(player2)
    roundnum+=1
    print ("It is now round", roundnum)
    if player1>=21:
        print("Player1 wins")
    if player2>=21:
        print("Player2 wins")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `take_turn` function,

```
    else:
        print (playernumber)
        return playernumber    # return the value back to the caller
```

In the while loop below,

```
while player1<=20 and player2<=20:
    player1 = take_turn(player1)    # update the value at each turn
    player2 = take_turn(player2)
```

In your case, the value of `player1` and `player2` never change, so the while loop never ends.

**Edit**

I guessed your logic and modified the function:

```
def take_turn(playernumber):
    dice1=randint(1,6)
    dice2=randint(1,6)
    dice3=randint(1,6)
    print (dice1,dice2,dice3)
    while dice1==dice2==dice3:
        if dice1==6:
            playernumber += 21
        dice1=randint(1,6)
        dice2=randint(1,6)
        dice3=randint(1,6)

    if dice1==6 and dice2==6:
        playernumber+=5
    elif dice1==6 and dice3==6:
        playernumber+=5
    elif dice2==6 and dice3==6:
        playernumber+=5
    elif dice1==6 or dice2==6 or dice3==6:
        playernumber+=1
    if roundnum==dice1 or roundnum==dice2 or roundnum==dice3:
        playernumber+= roundnum
    print (playernumber)
    return playernumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I also noticed that whenever all the dice values are the same it does not roll again but rather stops running. This is what I have:                                       if dice1==dice2==dice3:
            continue

Comment: I see the problem now. Actually your code has much more issues than that.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the value of `playernumber` inside the `take_turn` function, that is just a variable name defined in your function scope. You have to return the new score to the calling scope.

And in the calling scope you must assign the return value to your variable name.

```
def take_turn(playernumber):
    ...
    return playernumber

player1 = take_turn(player1)
player2 = take_turn(player2)
```